# How to save case values in variable

Tags: linux, shell, case

```
selection=

until [ "$selection" = "0" ]; do

  echo ""
  echo "PROGRAM MENU"
  echo "1 - display free disk space"
  echo "2 - display free memory"
  echo ""
  echo "0 - exit program"
  echo ""
  echo -n "Enter selection: "
  read selection
  echo ""
  case $selection in
      1 ) df ;;
      2 ) free ;;
      0 ) exit ;;
      * ) echo "Please enter 1, 2, or 0"
  esac
echo $selection

done
```

If I press 2 it's showing free space and echo is showing 2, but I need echo is "free".

Comment: When you say "exit" you are running a command `exit` so the rest of your code isn't executed.  There is no point in the `until` test you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The selection is used by the case statement to decide what to do.  It is not set by the case statement.

You might want to try something like this instead:

```
selection=

until [ "$selection" = "0" ]; do

  cmd=''

  echo ""
  echo "PROGRAM MENU"
  echo "1 - display free disk space"
  echo "2 - display free memory"
  echo ""
  echo "0 - exit program"
  echo ""
  echo -n "Enter selection: "
  read selection
  echo ""

  case "$selection" in
      1) cmd='df' ;;
      2) cmd='free' ;;
      0) cmd='exit' ;;
      *) echo "Please enter 1, 2, or 0"
  esac

  if [ -n "$cmd" ] ; then 
    echo "selection $selection is '$cmd'"
    $cmd
  fi

done
```

Note that it runs the `echo "selection $selection is '$cmd'` before executing `$cmd`, otherwise it will exit before the `echo` when `$selection` is 0.

Comment: There's still no point in the test passed to `until`.  It will never be true.

Comment: it evaluated to true when i ran it and entered 0.  it may be a far from optimal way to write the script, but it's not actually wrong.

Comment: How?  It should have run the `exit` command before it reached that point of the code.  (Actually, I think it *did* run the `exit` command, and you assumed it reached the `until` test.)  ;)

Comment: true. but it makes no practical difference unless (as i mentioned in my answer) you intend to run something inside the loop AFTER `$cmd`.  It does evaluate to true (and end the loop) if you, e.g., replace `exit` with `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

> if i press 2 its showing free space and echo is showing 2
>   but i need echo is "free"

So, currently `echo $selection` prints `2` for free and you want it to print `free`.  In that case, replace:

```
  2 ) free ;;
```

With:

```
  2 ) free; selection=free ;;
```

With the variable `selection` set to the string `free`, this cause the `echo` command to print what you want.

#### Alternative

As another option, but *not* an exact replacement, the bash command `select` can be used to accomplish something similar with a much shorter code:

```
PS3="Please enter 1, 2, or 3: "
select selection in "display free disk space" "display free memory" "exit program"
do
  case "$selection" in
      "display free disk space") df ;;
      "display free memory") free; selection=free ;;
      "exit program") exit ;;
  esac
  echo $selection
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this.  Might be helpful/instructive.

```
#!/bin/bash

menu() {
  cat >&2 <<EOF

PROGRAM MENU

1 - display free disk space
2 - display free memory

0 - exit program

EOF
}

while true; do
  menu
  read -p "Enter selection: " selection
  case "$selection" in
    1)
      echo df
      df
      ;;
    2)
      echo free
      free
      ;;
    0)
      echo exit
      exit
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Please enter 1, 2 or 0" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: that's a better way of writing this script (except why run `menu` twice? just run menu on the line immediately after the `while true`)....but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @cas, there.  Now it does.